# How to replace part of a string using values from another column in a data frame in Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, str-replace

I have a df with the following columns:

```
df = {'cat1': [np.nan, 2, 1,3], 'cat2':[3,2,np.nan,5], 'cat3':[np.nan,np.nan,4,1], 'col4':['Text text text XXX Cat errors are present.', 'Text text text XXX Cat errors are present.', 'Text text text XXX Cat errors are present.', 'Text text text XXX Cat errors are present.']}
```

For any cat1, cat2 and cat3 columns that is not null, I want to replace the string "XXX" in col4 with the value in the cat1-cat3 columns, and the "Cat" with the title of the columns.

The desired output is:

```
'col4': ["Text text text 3 cat2 errors are present.", "Text text text 2 cat1 and 2 cat2 errors are present.", "Text text text 1 cat1 and 4 cat3 errors are present.", "Text text text 3 ca1, 7 cat2 and 5 cat3 errors are present."]
```

I’ve tried the following and this is as far as I got:

I put the 7 possible combinations into variables

V1 = df.cat1.notnull() & (df.cats2.isnull() & df.cats3.isnull())
V2 = df.cat2.notnull() & (df.cats1.isnull() & df.cats3.isnull()
...

I’m thinking it involves something like this:

df.loc[V1, ‘col4’] = df.col4.replace(‘XXX’, df.cat1, regex=True)

But this doesn’t work and I can’t seem to figure out how modify the other part to add the column name based on the not null condition. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your obsession with cats, but please show your efforts at least.

Answer (score 0):

As I have not really put too much effort into using Pandas at this point in my career, some of the following code may be unnecessary and there may be simple built-in Pandas functions that do the same thing more effectively.  That being said, one thing that you mentioned was checking for null values, but they are `np.nan`s so you are going to have to use the special function `np.isnan()`.  Once again, there is most likely a simpler method to extract rows than the one that I used, but what I did was extract the rows and create individual strings to replace `XXX`.  The following was my attempt, which did yield the desired results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': [np.nan, 2, 1,3], 'cat2':[3,2,np.nan,5], 'cat3':[np.nan,np.nan,4,1], 'col4':['Text text text XXXare present.', 'Text text text XXXare present.', 'Text text text XXXare present.', 'Text text text XXXare present.']})

fd = df.transpose()

dic ={}
for idx, col in enumerate(fd):
    dic[col] = []
    for i in range(3):      
        dic[col].append({df.columns[i]:fd[idx][i]})
    exec('row%s = ""' % idx)

i = 0
for key, values in dic.items():
    for value in values:    
        for k,v in value.items():
            if not np.isnan(v):             
                exec('''row%s += str(int(v)) +" " + k + " errors, "'''% i)
    i+=1

rows = [row0,row1,row2,row3]

for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, "col4"] = df.loc[i,"col4"].replace("XXX", (rows[i]))

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)

print(df)
```

I am sure that you will be able to use something in the above code to figure out how exactly you want to implement your desired functionality, most likely in a more succinct way.